# Developer Tools in Google Chrome not showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm just moved to windows 10.
And have latest version of Google Chrome on it.
But whenever I tried to access developer’s tool it shows nothing.
I have tried,
1) Right Click + Inspect element.
2) F12.
3) Right corner tab on Google chrome + more tools + developers tool.
But none of them working.
Please help.....
I don't know what is missing.

Comment: Can you check this my answer. https://superuser.com/a/1290703/868034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing i would try is closing all processes and restarting Chrome and if that doesn't work i would uninstall and reinstall chrome

I know this isn't really an answer but hope it might help

Goodluck!

Comment: If i helped you please give me the green tick :)

Comment: It is worth trying gianni's suggestion below before you go for re-installation.

Comment: without uninstall we can also resolve this issue. this is not a perfect answer as per my knowledge

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue but in my scenario I was on a Virtual Machine with some complex display settings. The procedure here worked for me in other contexts:

1. You should see the process in the Windows bar on the bottom of your screen.
2. When you click on it, nothing is shown.

#### Bring back in the viewport

If the conditions above apply, then the window is simply displayed out of the display viewport. TO bring it back, do the following:

3. Make sure you have selected the window in the Windows bar.
4. Hit ALT + SPACE to show the menu
5. Select "Maximize".
6. The window should appear in one of your monitors.
7. Drag it around and resize it.

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same problem. The window is apparently minimized.
On windows, hold the mouse on the chrome icon in the taskbar, when the thumb shows up, right click on it and select maximize window.

Comment: Solution worked. However, i don't think its problem of window being minimized AFAIK, but something else.

Comment: Great  same in the MAC. dev window was minimized to a very tiny. Thanks.

Comment: I just had this issue, finally resolved the issue thanks to this answer!

Answer (score 4):

You should try also Ctrl+Shift+I for windows as written on the following doc

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this of this way

- Open chrome dev tools
- using the chrome page that you need debug press Win + "<" (left arrow)
- windows ask you which window you want to the right and select chrome dev tool icon, but click should be in the icon instead of the rectangle of the windows

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Chrome -> Setting -> Extensions (Side Menu) -> Turn on Developer Mode

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, The thing is just minimized. Hover over the side of the options at the bottom and drag to top and you will see the options.

[see following image and hover over ht area highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Itbq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your dev-tool might be on your second monitor, which you are not looking at but connect with your PC.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Please try this at your own risk, I'm not fully aware of its consequences. It apparently clears chrome's local storage for all websites*

All the solutions I saw didn't work for me, but this one did:

I deleted this folder:

```
// AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\leveldb
```